# Cookies are not deleting

Tags: php, cookies

I am using this code to set my cookies:

```
setcookie("user", $_POST['IGN'], time()+86400, "/", "chipperyman.com");
setcookie("session", file_get_contents("/passes/".$_POST['IGN']."/cookieID.txt"), time()+86400, "/", "chipperyman.com");
```

I am using this to delete my cookies:

```
setcookie("user", "", time()-3600);
unset($_COOKIE['user']);
setcookie("session", "", time()-3600);
unset($_COOKIE['session']);
```

However, the cookies are never deleted. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

`unset` only deletes them from memory on the server. You should send an empty cookie down to the client or one that has expired in the past.

Comment: I did with the `setcookie`.

Comment: maybe do more than just an hour. timezones might be different.

Comment: I set it to time()-360000, and the timezone is the same as my computer's time. It still didn't work.

Comment: can you post the real response.